# Exercise 6.79 from Rotman's Advanced Modern Algebra

Tags: abelian-groups

If $G$ is a nonzero abelian group show that

$$\operatorname{Hom}_{\Bbb Z}(G,\frac{\Bbb Q}{\Bbb Z}) \neq \{0\}.$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f: n \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Q}/ \mathbb{Z}$ be any homomorphism of groups. Then we may extend this homomorphism to $\tilde{f}: \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Q}/ \mathbb{Z}$ by putting $\tilde{f}(1)=f(n)/n$.
Thus by [Baers Criterion](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injective_module#Baer.27s_criterion) $\mathbb{Q}/ \mathbb{Z}$ is an injective group.

Now pick any nonzero element in $g\in G$ and define a nontrivial homomorphism 
$f: <g> \rightarrow \mathbb{Q}/ \mathbb{Z}$( we can set $f(g)$ to be any nonzero element of $\mathbb{Q}/ \mathbb{Z}$ if the order of $g$ is infinite. If the order of $g$ is $n$, then we set $f(g)=1/n$). Since $\mathbb{Q}/ \mathbb{Z}$ is injective we can extend $f$ to a nonzero morphism $\tilde{f}: G \rightarrow \mathbb{Q}/ \mathbb{Z}$.